# Where do I find the Google Talk plugin once it is installed?

Tags: 10.04, internet, google-video

When I try to download google video chat plugin, it tells me that my country is restricted from using their services , however I manage to do it using some software. Where is it installed in my computer so that when I do a clean install of Ubuntu's new version I just copy that to my new install?

Answer (score 5):

If you downloaded the `.deb` file, you can use the same file to install on another Ubuntu installation and if you installed it using a repository, the file is in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.

To remove the Google video plugin on Ubuntu from the command-line:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-talkplugin
```

You will still have to kill the process manually:

```
ps auxw | grep Google | grep -v grep
```

The first number displayed is the *process identifier* for the Google Talk Plugin. Kill it with:

```
kill -9 #
```

Where `#` is the *process identifier*.

Comment: google video chat plugin does not come in .deb form , what it does is that it checks where you are requesting it from and if it is a legal country it installs it automatically,I do have the google talk plugin in .deb form but not the video plugin

Comment: You mean the plugin used to enable video chat in gmail right in the browser, right? If yes, it is available as a DEB file. I download it from here http://www.google.com/chat/video/download.html 

here is my own 64bit deb file http://db.tt/8O8FuMR

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Google Video and Chat plugin from the page http://www.google.com/chat/video/
and you can use for Audio/Video PC to PC calls anywhere in the world.

You can also place Audio/Video calls with any Empathy user (the default IM/Audio/Video chat program in Ubuntu).

What is not available around the world is phonecalls to telephone numbers. It is currently only available to the US and Canada.

> Note: Installing Google voice and
>   video chat will add the Google voice
>   and video chat repository so your
>   system will automatically keep Google
>   voice and video chat up to date. If
>   you don't want Google voice and video
>   chat's repository, do "sudo touch
>   /etc/default/google-talkplugin" before
>   installing the package.

And finally, how do you use the Google Talk plugin? Just log in to your GMail account, select a contact, you will be able to see that you can have a video chat (you get the option for video chat if they have a camera, or the video chat icon is greyed).

[image]

How do you verify that the Google Talk plugin is installed in Firefox? Simply visit in Firefox `Tools->Addons->Plugins` and look for the Google Talk plugin.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using google chrome then just type in the address bar

about:plugins

then on the top right side of the screen click details and that will show you the paths of all your plugins i'm sure there will be a way of doing this in firefox but i do not have it installed so i can't check

EDIT: just checked i do have firefox lol it works the same **about:plugins** but it doesn't show file paths but you can get the file name and use locate in the terminal to search and find its location

Answer (score 1):

Look at `/opt/google/talkplugin` directory.

Answer (score 1):

With the following command:

```
strings /opt/google/talkplugin/libnpgoogletalk.so | grep Version: | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

If **libnpgoogletalk.so** is somewhere else, then change path of file!